# Unable to copy file during docker build

Tags: docker

I'm trying to dockerize a basic Django application, but mounting the volume does not work.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.4-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ../backend-code:/code
```

Error message:

```
Building backend
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.7.4-alpine
 ---> 39fb80313465
Step 2/7 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6b971cbdc65e
Step 3/7 : RUN mkdir /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 598a375cf3c6
Step 4/7 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a222aaeaf660
Step 5/7 : COPY requirements.txt /code/
ERROR: Service 'backend' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder565677268/requirements.txt: no such file or directory
```

I've verified with:

```
winpty docker run --rm -it 123456 sh
```

That /code folder is empty. I also tried to use different folder names for target, but they do not appear inside the container. I even tested with non-existing volume directories (- ../nosuchdirectory:/code), and docker-compose didn't give any errors.

Folder structure:

```
.
├── docker
|   ├── docker-compose.yml
|   └── backend
|       └── Dockerfile
├── backend-code
|   ├── requirements.txt
|   ├── [django files]
```

I'm running the code on Windows 10. 
Docker Desktop community 2.1.0.3 stable.
Drive has been shared and "docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data" works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ERROR: Service 'backend' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder565677268/requirements.txt: no such file or directory**

This is the error you are getting. Its failing at this line

```
COPY requirements.txt /code/
```

Move the requirements.txt into the backend dir

```
.
├── docker
|   ├── docker-compose.yml
|   └── backend
|       └── Dockerfile
        --- requirements.txt <--
├── backend-code
|   ├── [django files]
```

Comment: That didn't work. The mounted files are nowhere to be found inside the container.

Comment: Then you need to put that file in your backend directory, next to the docker file. Otherwise, you won't be able to install Django. Do a quick web search on requirements.txt, its easy.

Comment: Actually, the requirements.txt is in the backend-code folder, with rest of the files related to the code. I edited the folder structure.

Comment: You mix things up. One you want to have the environment with dependencies in your normal docker build, not mounted. And then you want to mount the code folder backend-code into that environment. Requirements.txt need to be in backend not backend-code. At least with your current docker file.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Using copy ../../backend-code/requirements.txt doesn't work ("Forbidden path outside he build context"), but I copied it to backend folder. However, shouldn't the contents of backend-code be seen in /code/? That folder remains empty.

Comment: @notareal depends on how you start the services. You run:
`docker-compose up --build` ?

Comment: You can also run  `docker-compose run  --service-ports backend` if you want to run a single service and expose its ports.

Comment: Oh lol, I faced with the exactly same error `ADD . ./` copy all files except `requirements.txt` !!